# (wrong) hyphenation after apostrophe in Catalan

Tags: hyphenation, languages, apostrophe

In a  document in Catalan that I am writing in LaTeX,  some apostrophed words (e.g., "d’expressió") are wrongly hyphenated after the apostrophe (i.e., "d'-/expressió").

I am using:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[catalan]{babel}
```

and TeXstudio with (maybe not properly loaded?) Catalan dictionary.

Do you know the reason for this bad behavior and how to fix it? (In Catalan you should never break the line after an apostrophe.)

An MWE and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[catalan]{babel}
\setlength\textwidth{1sp}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\hspace{0pt}d'expressió
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of providing a compllable MWE (minimum working example). Feel free to revert.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Should be reported.  A message to tex-hyphen@tug.org should work for that.